# Underlying provided failed to open ? mvc4 , wcf

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

This code section i am getting error any ideas ?

```
  public IEnumerable<LOBinfo> getLobinfo()
        {
               // var obj = from n in lobj.LOBinfoes select n;
                 return lobj.LOBinfoes.Select(m=>m).ToList();
               // return obj.ToList();
        }
```

I am not even using USING keyword ?

This issue been for a while and i referred many articles in stackoverflow itself but things looking bad for me .

Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Underlying provider failed to open means, that at some point a database could not be reached, due to wrong connection settings for example or a previous failure etc...

The code you show here is allright, except for the fact you write a useless .Select you can drop the .Select(m=>m) and just leave the .ToList there.

Further, to find out what is causing your crash post the exact error message as well as the inner exception. (and the inner exception's inner exception and so on...)

Next to that the part "lobj.LOBinfoes" is probably a repository or something? You might as well post the code of that and the code of your data access object as well.

Comment: yes ur right actually i kept my dbfile.sdf not in App_data FOLDER later now i moved to App_data everything working fine .

Comment: Ty so much for reply and your efforts are truly appreciated . Cheers mate